# ldap authentification with windows credential

Tags: asp.net, windows, authentication, ldap

I have a website in asp.NET 4.0 and I can not connect to LDAP without password.
I tried with null values ​​for the login and password but I have a domain error.
I try to retrieve the user information linked to the windows session.

Thank for the help.

Comment: Did you found an answer ?

Comment: Yes, if you don't put a password, the user's account will be used

Comment: can you share your code (partial code) via github ?

Comment: you can answer yourself